# Can we be too analytical

Tags: philosophy

It seems to me that analysing everything to the tiniest degree takes joy and spontaneity out of life. I admit, being mindful can make for better decision making and therefor better outcome, but do you want to be around me if I am so thoroughly earnest?

Comment: odd question, i'm voting to close. some people like earnest people, others do not.

Comment: I am genuine in my question. Although from a young child I taught myself to meditate, I have never studied Buddhism. There has been a shift inside me that is calling me, at age 57 to ask questions about this religion. Standing outside and looking in at Buddhism, that is one of my concerns... that people can become too scholarly in their practice, and miss the emptiness that I have discovered from my meditation whilst knowing nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I think i get what you mean and being too analytical can seem strange because one will definitely be no fun at a party nor is one likely to participate to begin with. However being constantly serious and ardently training is going to make one more happy and one will be able to benefit other people in a far more useful way.

Answer (score 1):

One can be sharply analytical in all matters, but also warm towards all fellow beings.  We can find joy from fellowship even as we analyse our fellow beings' behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Its okay if thats your nature,there is nothing really wrong ,thats what you discover from mindfulness ,there are dimensions in life ,not all people are going to be mindful or anything in particular.Analysis thats also a dimension of life ,it also has its own beauty ,attachment to a dimension is the issue but that is also natural and happens ,from that understanding one is spontaneous even in analysis ,analysis then comes out of your spontaneity ,spontaneity is not against it ,it simply chose to do it.The spontaneity of another person may choose intellect or basketBall they are all dimensions of life.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want to be an automobile designer, mechanic, driver or passenger. -)

Comment: I got 8 marks for my answer. Why?

Comment: It was upvoted (+10) and downvoted (-2).

Comment: I am pleased you received good marks for this answer. It was wonderful

Answer (score 0):

One of the oddest concepts in Buddhism is "neutral feeling." The neutral feeling is neither pleasant nor painful. And how should we deal with that neutral feeling?

> The underlying tendency to ignorance should be given up when it comes to neutral feeling.” [MN44](https://suttacentral.net/mn44/en/sujato)

In other words, we should not wallow in "meh indifference" when feeling neutral. Instead, we should understand:

> “What is the counterpart of neutral feeling?”
>   “Ignorance.”
>
> “What is the counterpart of ignorance?”
>   “Knowledge.”

Knowledge requires effort, practice and insight. It also requires restraint. And restraint is important given that thinking is one of the six senses. In particular they:

> know a thought with their mind. If it’s pleasant they don’t hold on to it, and if it’s unpleasant they don’t dislike it. They live with mindfulness of the body established and a limitless heart.
>   [sn35.247](https://suttacentral.net/sn35.247/en/sujato)

In other words analysis paralysis is not mindful practice. Nor is blind action taken in ignorance without thought to consequence. Right mindfulness balances effort with restraint guided by right view.

What do you think?

Comment: I think you have made a clear evaluation and answered my question well. In an earlier post I made someone commented about my placidity. Perhaps my ego has wrongly seen my acceptance and endurance as a strength. I need to engage more.

Comment: ❤️  I walk meditation listening to the suttas. I find that endlessly engaging.

Answer (score 0):

> When the thought is binding you the truth is hidden 
>   for everything is murky and unclear. And the burdensome practice of judging 
>  
>   brings annoyance and weariness. What benefit can be derived 
>   from distinctions and separations?

Training is, first and foremost, about intimacy.  You can't be fully and wholeheartedly intimate with the world if you are caught up in internal analysis.  The smallest, discursive thought sets you miles apart from experiencing the way.  Just let things be in there own way.  Don't actively seek enlightenment.  Don't actively try to be mindful.  When you walk, really walk.  When you eat, really eat.  If there is even a single remainder of your mind that isn't fully walking or fully eating, you've gone astray.

> If the eye never sleeps,
>  all dreams will naturally cease.
>  If
>   the mind makes no discriminations,
>  the ten thousand things are as
>   they are,
>  of single essence.

(Quotes from the Verses on the Trusting Heart)

Comment: Wow! That’s powerful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a misnomer here. Mindfulness does not equal analytical. In fact, being analytical can be antithesis of the mindfulness.

**In example:**
For instance, when I am greeted by a friend, I will get happy. Now if I were to analyze this, my mind may say this feeling is rising due to some mental quality and this related to some form of bhāvanā or one could dive deeper and put it into terms of conciousness in the Yogacara tradition.

**In a mindfulness approach**, one would see that happiness is rising from the base of my chest and one may realize that we long for that feeling. Simply noting it, but not analyzing its means or it's path.

It is said that if one were to try and understand the complex interworkings of kamma, their head would explode. Kamma and Pratītyasamutpāda are nonlinear functions. We must learn to understand them through observation, which adds to why we cannot learn the dhamma through words but practice alone. **In short, yes you can be too analytical, but one can not be too mindful.**

**Note:** One may feel stress from being "mindful", but indeed they are not being truly mindful. Typically this comes from judgemental noting, rather than noting and feeling for what is truly going on. If your mindfulness is tiring, it is not being done correctly.

**Practice Notes:** If you find that you are taking joy from being too analytical, try watching that analysis. What type of views are you holding with the analysis? Are you trying to be a "good" buddhist? Are you reinforcing views that you are not good enough? So on and so forth. The true beauty of Buddhism comes from watching the arising and ceasing of phenomena. Watch the happiness arise, watch the mind cling, and then watch the mind release from that clinging. Watch the experiencing of freedom in that moment.

May you be safe. May you be happy. May you be free.